# Short URL on MediaWiki on Heroku

Tags: heroku, mediawiki

I have insatlled mediawiki on Dokku ( which is basically same as heroku.)  I have followed the following steps.

https://gist.github.com/caseywatts/d04bda6626ef2c6c8f97

Now I want to change the URL structure of the url if the articles.
I read up this -:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL

Now it asks to change config in Apache/Nginx. But since it is in PaaS, i do not have control over that. How would i go about if I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem; solved it by using Apache config instead:

`Procfile`:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -C apache_app.conf
```

`apache_app.conf`:

```
## http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache

# Enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Short URL for wiki pages
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

# Redirect / to Main Page
RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
```